# ag-grid checkboxes selection event too slow for angular to detect the changes

Tags: angular, angular-material, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular2-changedetection

I am using [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) with Angular 8.
Since I use it on many occasions in different views, I encapsulated the ag-grid component in my own angular component implementation.
Now it comes pre-configured and I only have to pass an array for the table data and an array for the selection.

example:

```
<myGrid 
    [rowData]="myTableData"
    [(selection)]="mySelection"
    (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"
>
</myGrid>
```

Based on the selected rows, the buttons in my view are enabled or disabled. And this works pretty well when I click directly on the rows in ag-grid.

**MyProblem**

*When I use checkboxes* and I click directly on the checkboxes, the buttons don't get updated. When I click on the rows there is no problem, it's when clicking on the checkboxes where the buttons are not updated.

Everything else is fine. The selection is made in the table, I can even log the selected rows, the "onSelectionChange" event is triggered.. Just the buttons don't get notified.

**My explanation**

The view is not updated after the selection was made. Either the event that updates the view is already finished before the selection is made, or the selection over checkboxes does not trigger any change detection.

**My workaround**

Using `ChangeDetectorRef#detectChanges()`.

-> I click on a checkbox in my grid 
-> (in `MyGrid` component) ag-grid triggers the `onSelectionChanged` function 
-> an event to an `@Output` is emitted by calling `this.selectionChange.emit(this.selection);` 
-> the parent components implement the `selectionChange($event)` function and triggers an `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`

**My actual question**

**WHY?**. Why does angular not detect the changes when I click on the checkboxes but only when I click anywhere else?

Here is more setup in more details:

**In MyGrid component**

```
@Input('rowData') public rowData: any[] = [];         // the array with the data for my table
@Input('selection') public selection: any[] = [];     // the array that holds my selected rows
@Output() private selectionChange = new EventEmitter<any[]>();  // bi-directional so I can get and set the selection from within my parent component
```

**EDIT**
I added the complete options here. As you can see they are kept rather simple, so the parent component can initialise them as needed.
**/EDIT**

```
 this.agGridOptions = {
  context: {thisComponent: this},
  pagination: true,
  paginationAutoPageSize: true,
  rowDeselection: false,
  rowSelection: this.rowSelectionMode,        // parameterizable
  suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns: true,
  suppressMakeColumnVisibleAfterUnGroup: true,
  groupUseEntireRow: true,
  rowGroupPanelShow: 'always',
  animateRows: true,
  sideBar: this.sideBar,                      // parameterizable
  defaultColDef: this.defaultColDef,          // parameterizable
  columnDefs: this.columnDefs,                // parameterizable
  getRowHeight: this.rowHeight,               // parameterizable
  onModelUpdated: () => this.sizeColumns(),
  onSelectionChanged: () => this. onSelected(),
  onGridReady: ($event) => this.onGridReady($event),
  getContextMenuItems: ($event) => this.getContextMenuItems($event)
};

// and once the onSelectionChanged is triggered this function is called:

onSelected() {
  this.selection = this.agGridApi.getSelectedRows();  // I update my bi-directional array for the selected rows
  this.selectionChange.emit(this.selection);          // and trigger the selectionChange event so the parent component knows that something happened
}
```

Now in my parent component, I have to implement this:

```
onSelectionChange($event: any[]) {
   this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();            // otherwise angular won't update my buttons
}
```

**EDIT**
And here is how the array with the `columnDefs` is initialised:

```
this.columnDefs.push(
     // some factory function that creates something like this:
     {
        headerName : 'Some Column',     // ex: "Employee"
        field : 'fieldOfTheModelClass', // ex: employee.name
        filter : 'agTextColumnFilter',  // (for example)
        checkboxSelection : true,       // the checkbox causes the problem
        valueGetter :  null,            // by default
        cellClass :  'someCssClass'     
        cellRenderer : renderName()     // a function to render the column value (if anything other than a string), maybe an image or icon
     }        
);
```

Comment: haven't you set the ChangeDetectionStrategy of your component to on push?

Comment: unfortunately that's not it. I tried setting the strategy explicitly but neither strategy works - so now it is back to `default`.

Comment: Could you paste more code here? maybe the gridOptions

Comment: @huanfeng I added the complete options. What else could be of interest here?

Comment: what's your columnDefs definition?

Comment: I added how I create the column definitions. It's all wrapped with factory functions but the output is pretty simple. The problem is the `checkboxSelection`. When the user clicks on the checkbox, then the parent class is not notified of the selection. When the user clicks anywhere else on the row it works...